# Sync wordpress plugin updates to git repo

Tags: wordpress, git, ftp

I have a wordpress site that I am finally getting into git. Previously I was editing changes locally and uploading via ftp. I want to come up with a strategy to be able to do the following:

1. Update my git repository with any changes made on the ftp server (plugin updates etc). That I will then sync that down into my local copy
2. Push locally tested changes into git and then deploy via ftp (I know how to do this part)

I don't know the best way to approach 1 and I'm very new to using git (usually use svn).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a conventional development workflow on Wordpress is challenging.

Because WP puts too much in the database, including site config, it makes syncing changes from one environment to the other a real pain.

We have a number of WP installs (against my better judgement) and organise our workflow like this.

*You might lighten this process if you're not part of a dev team and are going alone.*

---

**Local Dev**

codebase changes only.  Including shortcode development and templating.  This lives under a GIT workflow (branches, tags, etc).  Plugin/framework updates are installed here, and tested before adding to the gitball.

---

**Beta Live**

All content is built here, with any code based changes being requested as needed.   Testing is carried out here, responsive, UAT etc.

Code changes are pushed up via deployment scripts which trigger either a GIT pull, or by syncing files via ssh:rsync. [heres](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-hooks-to-automate-development-and-deployment-tasks) a good resource on how to use git hooks for this.

---

**Live**

For live deployment, we use a [WP database migration plugin](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/database-sync/) to get content across, and the git repository to push tagged releases up to the live server.  We also use the sync tool to pull down up to date copies of the database to our local dev machines.

I'm sure there are lots of other opinions on what's best, and how to implement them.

---

**My opinion**

> The fact is is that WP is a bad choice for websites that require a lot of under the hood attention.  It was never designed for this, and consequently is a real pain to force into a proper development cycle.  If I must use a CMS, I generally use Drupal for sites that need more functionality, its a steeper learning curve, but more than worth it.

Comment: Thanks for this! I get that it's not the best tool for the job but it's morphed for what it once was and there's not enough budget/time flying around to take the plunge right now. At some point a move will have to be made. What you say above makes sense, I'm wondering how you handle a case where a plug in might insert config/settings into the db?

Comment: then sync the database with local, install there, then re-migrate the db back to production again. Its a pain in the bum, but it works ok and you get to test properly first.

Comment: OK, I'll look into doing this! Would have thought there would be a better way of doing this by now. Thanks so much for your guidance!

Comment: youre welcome. I konw what you mean, we've been battling with trying to find a suitable process for months.  But at the end of the day, wordpress is written for blogging, by people that only do blogging.  Its just not setup to be anything else and its when we force it out of that scope that things get sticky.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow a git flow pattern. This consist of three main branches:

- **master**
- **release**
- **develop**

Preform all of your development in the **develop** branch which you would build and test locally. Then when you are ready to test on a server merge your changes into the **release** branch for testing. When everything checks out you can then merge into your **master** branch. From here you can either manually ftp the files from the **master** branch like you have been or set up a deployment hook to automate deployment to your server when changes are detected.

As your project grows you can implement a couple of other branches to further maintain your build. You can base a new branch **feature** off of **develop** when you need to add a new feature then merge it back into **develop** following the flow back up again. As well as a **hotfix** branch to take care of any bugs "on the fly" straight off the **master** branch.

Here is a good example of the git flow pattern:
[http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/][1]

*This article goes into a lot more detail about the git flow pattern and is an awesome resource!*

*Be sure that whenever you start a new development phase you merge from **master** to **develop** so you know you are starting with the most recent version of your project.*

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. So what I was refering to when I said server was the ftp server. This doesn't address pulling down the changes directly made on the files on the ftp server.

Comment: In order to do this you would have to have a git repo with those changes in it on the server that you could clone from.